# How to achieve same physics on different screen sizes?

Tags: java, android, game-physics, screen-size

Is there any elegant way of calculating velocities, sizes and distances so that they end up the same on every screen size?

I tried a lot of things, including scaling factors etc. but it didn't work. Everything ended up having super weird sizes as soon as the screen size wasn't 1920x1080 anymore.

**EDIT:**
I fixed it. I now create the objects using fractions of the screen width for the sizes. 
I divide every hard-coded velocity I use by `1080 / screenWidth` or `1920 / screenHeight`, respectively, so that they are the same on every screen size.

So I still use scaling factors, but I use them way less frequently, and I think I sometimes used them in wrong places.

**Now the question is:** Now that everything is scaled with the screen width, how can I support devices with other ratios than 16:9? I tried to find out which of the sides is closer to the 16:9 frame and then use that one to scale everything properly, but that cannot work as I found out. How do games handle different screen ratios?

Comment: Why not just use the units Android already has for this sort of thing, `dp`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp

Comment: Also realize that screens don't have the same height/width ratio. Any hardcoded value like 1080 won't work.

Comment: Determine a base dimension where the physics work in the manner that you prefer. Then, for screens of different dimensions, obtain the scaling factors in the x and y dimensions relative to the base dimension. Finally, use these x and y scaling factors on the quantity of interest, e.g. velocity.

Comment: @TheWanderer i read that question before I started and tried to kind of implement my own dp...

Comment: @jrd1 that's what I did and I am unhappy with the solution because firstly I made a mistake somewhere and secondly I don't think this is a very pretty solution... Isn't there some elegant trick for that? If there isn't I guess I'll have to do the same thing again and hope I don't mess it up again, which would be annoying

Comment: @Finni: According to what you've written, you've _inverted_ the x scaling factor. IMO, there isn't a cleaner solution than involving scaling factors - anything else wouldn't be as adaptable, intuitive, or maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use the `height` of the given `16 : >9` display and calculate the `width` it would have on a screen with a `16 : 9` display, then I calculate everything as if that was the actual width. Everything is drawn with an offset of `(actualWidth-wantedWidth)/2f` so that the objects appear centered. The same is possible for the height, if the ratio is `16 : <9`

So in a nutshell: if the screen ratio doesn't fit, I make it fit by putting (black or textured) bars around my desired space.